# How do I get an else statement to only print out a result after the entire file has been iterated through?

Tags: python

I have to write a python program for the following problem

Write a complete and syntactically correct Python program to solve the following
problem:
Write a program for the local coffee shop owner who wants to be able to control his
inventory. The program must be written in accordance with the following specs:

1. Write the following data to an external file, name the file coffeeInventory.txt
   Description Pounds
   Blonde Roast 15
   Medium Roast 21
   Flavored Roast 10
   Dark Roast 12
   Costa Rica Tarrazu 18
2. You do not need to write the table, just the data
3. Read in the records you just wrote to coffeeInventory.txt and display them on the
   screen and sum the total pounds of coffee
4. Append these records to the file
   Guatemala Antigua 22
   House Blend 25
   Decaf House Blend 16
5. Modify the file by allowing the owner to remove data from the file:
   a. Ask the owner to enter a description to remove
   b. If the description exists, remove the coffee name and the quantityc. If the description is not found, display the message: That item was not
   found in the file.
6. Modify the file by allowing the owner to delete data from the file:
   a. Ask the owner to enter a description to delete
   b. If the description exists, delete the coffee name and the quantity
   c. Replace the name and quantity of the coffee removed in step b by asking
   the user to enter a new coffee name and quantity
   d. If the description is not found, display the message: That item was not
   found in the file.

this is what I have so far

```
cof= open('coffeeInventory.txt', 'w')
cof.write('Blonde Roast: 15 pounds\n')
cof.write('Medium Roast: 21 pounds\n')
cof.write('Flavored Roast: 10 pounds\n')
cof.write('Dark Roast: 12 pounds\n')
cof.write('Costa Rica Tarrazu: 18 pounds\n')
cof.close()
cof=open('coffeeInventory.txt', 'r')
cof_read=cof.read()
cof.close()

sum_lb=15+21+10+12+18


cof=open('coffeeInventory.txt', 'a')
cof.write('Guatemala Antigua: 22 pounds\n')
cof.write('House Blend: 25 pounds\n')
cof.write('Decaf House Blend: 16 pounds\n')
cof.close()
sum_lb=sum_lb+22+25+16
cof=open('coffeeInventory.txt', 'r')
cof_read=cof.read()
cof.close()
print(cof_read)
print('Sum of pounds of coffee: ', sum_lb)


delete=input('Enter a coffee description to delete it: ')
cof=open('coffeeInventory.txt', 'r')
cof_read=cof.readlines()
cof.close()
new_cof=open('coffeeInventory.txt', 'w')
for line in cof_read:
    if delete.lower().replace(' ','') not in line.lower().replace(' ',''):
        new_cof.write(line)
    else:
        print("That coffee does not exist")
        
cof.close()

new_description=input("Enter a new coffee description and its weight in pounds.")

new_cof=open('coffeeInventory.txt', 'a')
new_cof.write(new_description)
new_cof.close()


new_cof=open('coffeeInventory.txt', 'r')
print(new_cof.read())
new_cof.close()
```

The problem I'm facing is that the line `That coffee does not exist` prints out for every line iterated instead of just once. How do I get it to only print out once the whole file has been iterated through?

Comment: Did you print ```delete.lower().replace(' ','')``` and check if it is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is a flag to save whether the Coffee was found.

```
found = False
for line in cof_read:
    if delete.lower().replace(' ','') not in line.lower().replace(' ',''):
        new_cof.write(line)
    else:
        found = True

if not found: 
    print("That coffee does not exist")
```

A more optimized way is the following. It assumes there's no duplicate coffee description in the file.

```
key = delete.lower().replace(' ','')
for line in cof_read:
    if found or (key not in line.lower().replace(' ','')):
```

Comment: Thank You so much!